# Can someone "live from farming"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to ask if I can say: People live from farming and animal husbandry. Would you rather say people live "off" farming?

Comment: In the sense they "make a living" from farming, I'd suppose.

Comment: "Live by..." is another possibility.

Comment: I wonder if would be a difference in how you'd express it between someone who actually works as a farmer and a person or community whose food is produced by farming (e.g. a farmer's family) or someone who lives off an income provided by farming (e.g. a landowner)? Maybe the question could clarify what is meant.

Comment: It's more common to say "derive a living", as in "people derive a living from farming and animal husbandry".

Answer (score 1):

According to Merriam-Webster Dictionary:
to live on (something) 
is an idiom.
It means:
to have or use (an amount of money) to pay for the things that one needs to live.
For example:
You can't live on this salary.
So the only possible way is to say: 'to live on farming'.